Is it permissible for a woman to wear perfume in public according to Islam?
Assalam alaykum,
I would like to know if it is permissible for a woman to wear perfume when she goes out in public according to Islamic teachings. I have heard different opinions on this matter and would like some clarification.
What are the hadiths or Quranic verses that address this topic?
What are the opinions of various scholars and Islamic schools of thought on this issue?
Is it possible to wear a light perfume that is not overly attractive?
Thank you in advance for your answers and clarifications.
Barakallahou fik.
